# How to autolaunch installer from dmg

Tags: macos, dmg

I want to deploy my program on Macintosh and I have a working installer but the installer and the files are packed into a zip file. I would like to make a DMG file and place them into it. This is easy to do but I would like the installer to start automatically when the user opens the DMG file. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: No I don't think it is possible.  The `.dmg` is a compressed disk image and I think the user must do the dragging themselves.  You can provide links within the `.dmg` to make this easier, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. What you need to do is convert your installer package to a flat package (these are now the default anyway). A flat package installer is a single file, so there's no need to bundle it into a zip or DMG.